# Editing a data.frame in R Studio does not work

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, edit

My Computer: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

RStudio: 1.4.1106

R: 4.0.4

The code is here.

```
edit(data.frame())
```

When I enter it in the console of RStudio, RStudio suspend.
Then I click the stop sign, a dialog shows and notifies me to "Terminate R". I clicked ok, but the RStudio still suspend as shown in the picture below.

I want to know:

1. Is the code correct to edit a data.frame?
2. If not, what's the right one?

[image]

Comment: No issues on my end. Does it crash if you open R (not R Studio) and run that line?

Comment: @Phil The RStudio just suspended. I added a picture to my question.

Comment: You ran it in R Studio. I'm asking what happens if you open R itself and run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Im running under R version 4.0.3 on macOS Catalina and your code does work for me. Try to update your R version.

You also may want to introduce your dataframe inside **edit()** so you can modify an existing dataframe. Otherwise you will modify an empty one.

Comment: Thanks. My R and RStudio are all the latest versions. I guess the reason is I installed XQuartz yesterday. Because the first time I input the code "edit(data.frame())
", then XQuartz launched automatically. It is so weird. I will figure it out.

Comment: XQuartz will launch automatically. However, you don't need XQuartz to run RStudio unless you need to connect to some server for any reason (and you work with Mac)